# Is there an option to use the phone's built in (If it exists) photo editor?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am currently using the `image_picker`  flutter package and I didn't see an option to crop (Using the phone's built in editor) the image that the user has picked.

Do you know if there is another plugin that can do that or if there is an option to do that with `image_picker`?

Comment: There is no "phone's default editor" on Android. There is no requirement for an Android device to have a photo editor, let alone one that offers cropping, let alone one that offers cropping on behalf of third-party apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, is there a way to check for an available photo editor and send the image there for editing?

Comment: @AlonYeager You can try sending an intent with ACTION_EDIT and the proper MIME type.  But the odds of it working on  Android are low-  very few people will have a photo editor installed.  Not sure on iOS if one exists or not

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for the advice, while trying that I encountered a PlatformException, I understand that I need to use a FileProvider but I couldn't find how to use it in flutter

Comment: @GabeSechan if your interested https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you please check the question out?